# Logging all Entity Framework queries in the debug window in DB-First Approach

Tags: entity-framework, linq, logging

I want to log the Entity Framework queries in my debug window. I could do that with the following line:

```
myContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

But how can I do that for all my queries in different functions and in different files?

Do I have to write this line everywhere?

Or is there a way to do this by writing a particular line of code to log every query at a single place.

As suggested, I have written the code in the constructor of the context but it's not working.

```
public partial class EkartEntities : DbContext
{
    public EkartEntities() : base("name=EkartEntities")
    {
        Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Also, it is not duplicate of [How to make EF log sql queries globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083470/how-to-make-ef-log-sql-queries-globally)
as the post contains the answer of Code-First approach where we can simply modify our constructor.

Comment: After writing your line of code, all queries against your database context will be logged, no matter in which function or file you use this context. You don't have to write this line of code again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make EF log sql queries globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083470/how-to-make-ef-log-sql-queries-globally)

Comment: @Oliver He has to write it once for every context.
You could extend the `IDbCommandInterceptor` and log for every command automatically.

Comment: Yes, you're right. If you like to overwrite it globally you could simply set this property within the constructor of your context. In that case every instance will do the log.

Comment: @iregular I am using DB-First approach so I tried to set the property within the constructor by making a partial class of the same name of the context but the control is not going there. I checked it by placing a breakpoint.

Comment: As @Oliver pointed out it should work if you configure it in the constructor of the context as it only has to be set once for every context. It's hard to get exactly why it is not working without any code.

Comment: @iregular Updated the post with the constructor code. Can you take a look and see what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it doesn't work, there are two possibilities: 1. `Debug.WriteLine()` is wrong configured and doesn't write where you want. 2. A different constructor is used to create your context. Set some breakpoints (in ctor and in lambda) to check if both are called.

Comment: @Oliver I checked it using breakpoints. The original context constructor is being called whenever the context object is created but the constructor I wrote in my partial class is not.

Comment: is the partial class part of the same assembly

Comment: @iregular Oops, it's not. But how can I write the constructor twice in the same assembly?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to extend a constructor in a partial class (I might be wrong). If it is because you want EF to generate the constructor for you - I believe it is possible by changing the template file EF uses to generate the model and context classes. I have never tried this myself, but maybe @Oliver has?

Comment: @Oliver Any suggestion?

Comment: You could write a factory method, that creates the context and sets the logger. Then you replace all your ctor calls with this factory method.

Comment: It's impossible to make a partial with a constructor when the other class already has one (which a generated context does). Either your code can't compile or the partial class is not in the same namespace (so effectively it's another, unrelated class).

Comment: @Oliver Thanks!

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, I get it now, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install global logger by adding the following class to the project containing your `DbContext` derived class:

```
class MyDbConfiguration : System.Data.Entity.DbConfiguration
{
    public MyDbConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogFormatter(
            s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s)));
    }
}
```

The class represents the so called [Code-based configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based) and in this particular case is used to automatically register `DatabaseLogFormatter` with the specified `Action<string>` for *all* `DbContext` derived types and instances in the project that contains it.

Answer (score -2):

I think it is better that you can refer to use SQL Server Profiler to capture all the queries to database.

If you are developing locally, SQL Profiler will be ideal for you.

Whatever kind of Linq Queries or Raw SQL Query can be captured by the profiler.